# Selecting MAX of a Value from multiple categories from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to get the max weight of Apple, Orange, Mango - there could be any number of fruits. Bold items from the table is what i would like to have my query response.

I know this can be done by partitioning the table for example:

```
SELECT fruits,max(weight) OVER(PARTITION BY fruits) 
FROM fruitstat
GROUP BY fruits;
```

But this is not getting my expected results. I need the ones which are the max weight fruits in its category.

| Fruits | Color | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Apple** | **red** | **23** |
| Orange | orange | 6 |
| Mango | yellow | 13 |
| Apple | red | 15 |
| Orange | orange | 19 |
| **Mango** | **yellow** | **16** |
| Apple | red | 44 |
| **Orange** | **orange** | **31** |
| Mango | yellow | 12 |
| Apple | red | 14 |
| Orange | orange | 22 |
| Mango | yellow | 11 |

Comment: SELECT fruits,max(weight) max_weight
FROM fruitstat
GROUP BY fruits;

Answer (score 1):

Just group the MAX(weight) by fruits:

```
WITH fruit AS
(
  SELECT 'Apple' as fruits,'red' as color ,23 as weight FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Orange','orange',6  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mango','yellow',13  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple','red',15     FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Orange','orange',19 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mango','yellow',16  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple','red',44     FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Orange','orange',31 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mango','yellow',12  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple','red',14     FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Orange','orange',22 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mango','yellow',11  FROM dual
)
SELECT fruits, MAX(weight)
  FROM fruit
 GROUP BY fruits;
```

P.S. MAX for the apple is 44, not 23, at least in your sample data

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `group by` on window functions. You can do this, instead.

First, sort the fruits weight by using `rank`.

```
select rank() over (partition by fruits order by weight) as rank, fruits, weight
from fruitstat
```

After that, you can use subquery to return the first value only.

```
select fruits, weight
from (select rank() over (partition by fruits order by weight) as rank, fruits, weight from fruitstat) a
where rank = 1
```